# How to get parent object in with.bind attribute of Aurelia Js

Tags: html, aurelia

I have constructor of ViewModel below:

```js
export class ViewModel{
  data_1 = {id: 1, name: 'John'};
  currency = {id: 1, name: 'USA'};
}
```

And in my html, I bind data by "with.bind":

```html
<div with.bind="data_1">
  <span textcontent.one-time="id"></span>
  <span textcontent.one-time="name"></span>
  <div with.bind="currency">
    <span text.content="name"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have problem when I want to bind my currency in data_1, it can't not recognize currency . How can I get currency?

Comment: This is the first time I've seen with.bind yet but I'll give it a go, I'm not sure if I've got any nested elements though... could it be that it's still looking for data_1 when you are pulling name? How would you distinguish between them?

Comment: Try to move the inner div ` <div with.bind="currency">` outside the outer div with `with.bind`.

Comment: @Chandermani this is just example for my problem that I got. I cant not move them outside with.bind="data_1". I need them inside.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just simplify and get rid of with.bind?

```
<div>
    <span textcontent.one-time="data_1.id"></span>
    <span textcontent.one-time="data_1.name"></span>
    <div>
      <span textcontent.one-time="currency.name"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: this is correct, as with isn't officially part of aurelia.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that `with` attribute doesn't provide a reference to `$parent` context. I'm not sure this is the best way to handle it but you can create your own custom attribute that would have `$parent`.

Based on the original [`with`](https://github.com/aurelia/templating-resources/blob/master/src/with.js):

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';
import {BoundViewFactory, ViewSlot, customAttribute, bindable, templateController} from 'aurelia-templating';

@customAttribute('with-parent')
@templateController
@inject(BoundViewFactory, ViewSlot)
export class WithParent {

    constructor(viewFactory, viewSlot) {
        this.viewFactory = viewFactory;
        this.viewSlot = viewSlot;
    }

    bind(executionContext) {
        this.executionContext = executionContext;
        this.valueChanged(this.value);
    }

    valueChanged(newValue) {
        if (!this.view) {
            newValue.$parent = this.executionContext;
            this.view = this.viewFactory.create(newValue);
            this.viewSlot.add(this.view);
        }
        else {
            this.view.bind(newValue);
        }
    }
}
```

and then usage is transparent:

```
<div with-parent.bind="data_1">

    <span textcontent.one-time="id"></span>
    <span textcontent.one-time="name"></span>

    <div with-parent.bind="$parent.currency">

        <span textcontent.one-time="name"></span>

        <div with-parent.bind="$parent.$parent.another">
            <span textcontent.one-time="name"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using $parent alongside with.bind now works as of aurelia-framework@1.1.5

For example, the following will add a view model reference (bar) to the parent rather than to foo

```
<element with.bind="foo">
    <child-element view-model.ref="$parent.bar"></child-element>
</element>
```

Answer (score -1):

$parent gives you a reference to your view model so $parent.currency